# setting up the protege-api

Tags: java, owl, protege

How do I run the example in the protege-api documentation? I failed to run it even after setting up the dependencies protege.jar,protege-owl.jar http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/ProtegeOWL_API_Programmers_Guide

The error is "method not found":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.SystemFrames.replaceFrame(Ledu/stanford/smi/protege/model/Frame;)V
```

Can someone suggest the detailed steps of setting up the dependencies?

Comment: The error points at incompatible versions of some jars. What version of Protege are you using? The instructions you have linked are from 2010, so likely not adequate for the latest Protege versions.

Comment: hello thanks...i created a java project with a simple program for creatig a jena model.In the referenced libraries i used protege.jar that is built from from the code downloaded here..

Comment: http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/ProtegeOWL_API_Programmers_Guide,followed by the protege-owl.jar from http://smi-protege.stanford.edu/svn/owl/trunk/edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl/protege-owl.jar?view=log&pathrev=806,when creating the jena model i got the above error

Comment: Should i use  jena api to query the ontology or are there any recent techniques to perform query.My objcetive is to acheieve the same functionality as that of DL query tab through java program.